# Varnish does not work on other port

Tags: varnish

I installed varnish on port 82 , but it's not working , the browser show me "The connection has timed out" but i can telnet my server with 82 port , varnish listened on 82 and apache listened on 82 , but varnish does not work on this port , when i changing varnish port to 80 and changing apache port to 82 it is work fine

Comment: Did you open port 82 on your firewall?

Comment: yes,i can connect to it from out of server with telnet , also i'm getting SSL connection error with chrome

Comment: And when you issue HTTP commands over the telnet connection, e.g. issue an `GET / HTTP/1.1 <LF> host: www.example.com <LF>`  does that return anything or possibly logs something in the varnish log?

Comment: I'm getting default page of cpanel in sending headers from telnet

Comment: and i'm getting 400 error in telnet now..